# How to delete a listbox item (text) from a listview in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a listview which displays text from a loaded dataset. 
I need to remove unwanted words that I listed in a listbox. 
How to do that in delphi? I tried to convert the items to a text in the listview but the code didn't work for me..
Here's what I wrote:

```
var
counter,k : Integer; //counters

begin
  counter := 0;
  k:=0;

  while counter <= listview1.Items.Count do
    for k := 0 to Listbox1.items.Count-1 do
      if listview1.Items.item[counter].Caption=listbox1.items[k]  then
      begin
        listview1.Items.item[counter].Delete;
        inc(counter)
      end;
end;
```

Comment: You better show the code you have sofar, even if not fully working.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to SO! For a quick overview of the site and how it works [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then also [read about asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Here is the code I wrote:

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error message or are the items just not deleted? If so: Are all not deleted or just some not deleted? Show us some sample data, what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this situation? Learn about debugging at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Debugging_the_Application_%28IDE_Tutorial%29

Comment: I dont get any error mesage and the code is executed. But just nothing happens for this procedure, nothing is deleted . I've added the words to the listbox directly in the form. The words are not deleted from the listview.

Comment: I  have a listview with lines containing the words from a text file; some of them are 'the, a , an, and...' which I would like to remove them. So I created a list box where I inserted into its properties the same items I want to remove...That's it. I couldn't upload a photo in here. Hope I was clear enough :(

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple things wrong with the code:

- You're only incrementing `counter` when you find a match, hence the
  loop will not terminate if you don't.
- You're using `<=` in the head of your while-loop, that will lead to
  an Access Violation in the last iteration, since you access
  the (n+1)-th element in the ListView with n elements.
- If you modify the ListView while iterating over it, you have to
  iterate from the back to the front. Suppose you find a match for the
  first item of the ListView, you will delete it, and
  `ListView1.Items[counter]` will be the item that was at index `counter+1`
  previously. You can avoid that by changing the order of the iteration
  (since deleting an element will not influence the following iterations), and breaking if you find a match.

Also, non-critical, but a question of coding style:

- You don't have to initialize loop variables for a for-loop (and the
  compiler should have hinted that the value assigned to k in line 2 is
  never used, which you shouldn't ignore)
- If you have a known number of iterations to perform, as you do for
  the outer loop, you usually want to use a for-loop.
- Your accessing of the items looks a little weird, though it probably
  works.

TL;DR, here's how I would write the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  var counter,k: integer;
begin
  for counter := ListView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do
    for k := 0 to ListBox1.items.Count-1 do
      if ListView1.Items[counter].Caption = ListBox1.Items[k] then
      begin
        ListView1.Items.Delete(counter);
        Break;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, I used the short one and it looks much more convincing. However, I still have the items not deleted from the listview. Can it be because I have a subitem (2nd column in the list view)? should I  remove it as well?

Comment: You should have given that additional information in the question! What do you want to happen when `Item.Caption` is in the `ListBox1`? Delete the whole item (including subitem) or only clear the `Caption`. In your own code you `Delete`. What if a `SubItem` is in the `ListBox1`? Delete the `Item` (inc. subitems), delete the `SubItem` only or clear the `SubItem`? As you see there are missing specifications.

Comment: @farache Stop expecting others to write all of your code. Learn from this excellent answer. Think for yourself. Do some debugging. In short, try a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the outer counter `counter` in the wrong place. It is easier to code the `counter` to count backwards when you delete items that are indexed by the counter. Try this:

```
var
  counter,k : Integer; //counters
begin
//  counter := 0;
//  k:=0;
  for counter := listview1.Items.Count-1 downto 0  do
  begin
    for k := 0 to Listbox1.items.Count-1 do
      if listview1.Items.item[counter].Caption=listbox1.items[k]  then
      begin
        listview1.Items.item[counter].Delete;
        Break;
      end;
  end;

end;
```